# OpenGL 4.1: Vertex Array Object draws nothing

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to draw some vertices and indices in OpenGL 4.1 using a vertex array object:

```
float vertices[] = {-0.8, -0.8, 0, 0.8, -0.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 0};
unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

After setting up the VAO and drawing it using glDrawElements(), I get an empty screen. I also tried using a simple pair of shaders just returning the original vertex position and a hardcoded colour, but no luck there either.

Here's the code which sets up the VBO and VAO:

```
unsigned int vertexArray;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

unsigned int vertexBufferID;
unsigned int indexBufferID;

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * vertexCount, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * vertexCount, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * indexCount, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And I draw the VAO using:

```
glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
```

Here's a trace of all OpenGL calls:

```
// Setup code

glViewport(0,0,1024,768)
glGetString(GL_RENDERER)="GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2" 
glGetString(GL_VENDOR)="NVIDIA Corporation" 
glGetString(GL_VERSION)="4.1.0 NVIDIA 359.46" 
glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)="4.10 NVIDIA via Cg compil..." 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glGenVertexArrays(1,000000000015F9B4)
glBindVertexArray(1)
glGenBuffers(1,000000000015F9D4)
glGenBuffers(1,000000000015F9F4)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,1)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,36,000000000015FA48,GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,false,36,0000000000000000)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,2)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,12,000000000015FA88,GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glClearColor(0.300000,0.300000,0.400000,1.000000)

// End of setup, here's the code rendering two frames (they just repeat):

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glBindVertexArray(1)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0000000000000000)
glGetError()=GL_NO_ERROR 
wglSwapBuffers(0000000069011A82)=true 

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glBindVertexArray(1)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0000000000000000)
glGetError()=GL_NO_ERROR 
wglSwapBuffers(0000000069011A82)=true
```

From what I can tell I'm doing what pretty much every tutorial says I should be doing, but for some reason nothing ever appears on my screen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data are tightly packed in the array, so the stride parameter in `glVertexAttribPointer`should be 0. By the way, if you declare static arrays, you should use `sizeof` to pass the size of the array instead of implementation dependent things like `4 * vertexCount`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: You were mostly right. A stride of 0 causes opengl to assume the array is tightly packed, and will calculate the correct stride value based on the other parameters. Passing in the correct stride regardless is not incorrect. However, I put the length of the array as the stride value, which of course does not work ><